# How to initialize Ext.Direct?

Tags: extjs, extjs-mvc, extjs4.2, ext-direct

I try to use Ext.Direct with the ExtJS 4 MVC structure, and I'm not able to add the provider.

I get the error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'addProvider' of undefined` while calling `addProvider`:

```
Ext.Direct.addProvider(Ext.app.REMOTING_API);
```

I tried both in `launch` of the application and in `init`of the controller.

```
Ext.define('Dir.Application', {
    require: [
        'Ext.direct.*',
        'Ext.data.*',
        'Ext.grid.*'
    ],
    launch: function(){
        Ext.Direct.addProvider(Ext.app.REMOTING_API);
    }
    ...
});
```

and

```
Ext.define('Dir.controller.Main', {
    init: function(){
        Ext.Direct.addProvider(Ext.app.REMOTING_API);
    }
    ...
});
```

both give the same error.

Where is the correct location to put `addProvider` into the code ?

### Update: applying the recommendations of @rixo.

```
Ext.define('Dir.Application', {
    view:['Grid'],
    requires: [
        'Ext.direct.*',
        'Ext.data.*',
        'Ext.grid.*'
    ],
    launch: function(){
        Ext.Direct.addProvider(Ext.app.REMOTING_API);
    }
    ...
});
```

My view is defining a store and a proxy:

```
Ext.define('Dir.view.Grid', {
    extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
    store: {
        proxy: {
            type: 'direct',
            reader:{root: 'table'},
            api: {
                create: QueryDatabase.createRecord,
                read: QueryDatabase.getResults,
                update: QueryDatabase.updateRecords,
                destroy: QueryDatabase.destroyRecord
            }
        }
    ...
    }
```

Now the first error is OK, but I receiver an error complaining that `QueryDatabase` is not defined. It gets defined through the provider at `Ext.Direct.addProvider(Ext.app.REMOTING_API);` but it is not ready when the view is loaded through the `views: []` declaration in the application definition.

Is there a way to get this working without nesting `Ext.application` inside `Ext.onReady` like in [my solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19381704/1951708)?
No nesting would be better for the MVC way like explained [here in the docs](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/guide/application_architecture).

Comment: Just to be sure, did you add a require statement (e.g.`Ext.require([
    'Ext.direct.*'])` ) somewhere before calling the singleton?

Comment: @overlordhammer Yes, it is in the `require` list in the application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `require` in your application definition won't do anything. It should be plural [`requires`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.Class-cfg-requires).

Also, you seem to have devised this in your own answer, but the name `Ext.direct.Manager` seems to be the favored by Sencha over `Ext.Direct` now.

**Edit**

According to the [docs](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.data.proxy.Direct-cfg-directFn), you can set your direct functions using a string. Apparently, this is intended to solve exactly the kind of problems you've run into.

This should work and fix your issue:

```
api: {
    create: 'QueryDatabase.createRecord',
    read: 'QueryDatabase.getResults',
    update: 'QueryDatabase.updateRecords',
    destroy: 'QueryDatabase.destroyRecord'
}
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the spelling problem. With `requires`, `Ext.direct.Manager` is now available in application `init` and `launch`. But the direct api is not yet available for `views:[]` and `stores:[]` declared in the application definition. You got me a step further, but not yet up to the goal.

Comment: Nice. Maybe you should add some example of this non working code for views and stores in your question.

Comment: So, have you tried it? Does it works the way I think it does?

Answer (score 1):

Probably you are missing the API definition before calling the provider, take a look to this definition from Sencha's examples page

> ```
> Ext.ns("Ext.app"); Ext.app.REMOTING_API = {
> "url": "php\/router.php",
> "type": "remoting",
> "actions": {
>     "TestAction": [{
>         "name": "doEcho",
>         "len": 1
>     }, {
>         "name": "multiply",
>         "len": 1
>     }, {
>         "name": "getTree",
>         "len": 1
>     }, {
>         "name": "getGrid",
>         "len": 1
>     }, {
>         "name": "showDetails",
>         "params": ["firstName", "lastName", "age"]
>     }], ...}]
> } };
> ```

It should be included as a javascript file inside your webpage

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="api.php"></script>
```

Something like [**this example**](http://jsfiddle.net/hZZ4H/).

Hope it helps.

Comment: No, it wasn't this either

Answer (score 1):

Adding Direct providers is better done before the Application constructor runs:

```
Ext.define('Foo.Application', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Application',

    requires: [
        'Ext.direct.Manager',
        'Ext.direct.RemotingProvider'
    ],

    name: 'Foo',

    constructor: function() {
        Ext.direct.Manager.addProvider(...);

        this.callParent(arguments);
    }
});

Ext.application('Foo.Application');
```

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for !

Comment: The `Direct` function names still have to be strings to get all work. @rixo's answer is more complete.

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution:

```
Ext.require([
    'Ext.direct.RemotingProvider',
    'Ext.direct.Manager',
    'Ext.data.proxy.Direct'
]);
Ext.onReady(function(){
    Ext.direct.Manager.addProvider(Ext.app.REMOTING_API);
    Ext.application({
        name: 'Dir',
        extend: 'Dir.Application'
    });
});
```

It doesn't look really nice, because it uses the ExtJS 4 application instantiation inside a Ext.onReady.
At least it works. Maybe there is a better solution ?